# MySQL and SQL Membership Provider : Can it be set to not use ints?

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, membership-provider

I'm setting up a new .NET MVC3 site and decided to use MySQL instead of MSSQL (mainly because I'm poor and hosting MSSQL based sites is getting expensive).

I was planning on using the SQL Membership Provider and with a bit of fiddling got it all hooked up. I can create users, browse around etc. That is, until I tried getting the logged in users GUID. Looking at the users table, it appears that the users are stored only with an INT, not a GUID.

Is there a way to force the MySQL provider (or would it be the .NET connector...) to use a GUID instead of an INT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Custom Membership User](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366730%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) and [Customize CreateUserWizard Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178342%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)